# Cmake can't copy dll

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion

First of all I am an absolute c/c++ noob so go easy on me.
I installed CLion and MinGW Compiler. Everything working as it should.
Then I installed Qt 6 and started a predefined project for Qt widget executable in CLion. Giving me 2 files `main.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(qt_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/lib/cmake")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(QT_VERSION 6)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core Gui Widgets)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui Qt6::Widgets)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    message(WARNING "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it "
            "(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"path/to/Qt/lib/cmake\" or -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)")
endif ()

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
if (WIN32)
    set(DEBUG_SUFFIX)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(DEBUG_SUFFIX "d")
    endif ()
    set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
        set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
            set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        endif ()
    endif ()
    if (EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
    endif ()
    foreach (QT_LIB ${REQUIRED_LIBS})
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/Qt${QT_VERSION}${QT_LIB}${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>")
    endforeach (QT_LIB)
endif ()
```

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton button("Hello world!", nullptr);
    button.resize(200, 100);
    button.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Qt cmake prefix path is correct is suppose and loading cmake project runs thorugh fine.
But when I try to build I get:

```
====================[ Build | qt_test | Debug ]=================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Moritz\CLionProjects\qt_test\cmake-build-debug --target qt_test -- -j 9
[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target qt_test
[ 25%] Built target qt_test_autogen
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable qt_test.exe
Error copying file "C:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/lib/cmake/../../bin/Qt6Cored.dll" to "C:/Users/Moritz/CLionProjects/qt_test/cmake-build-debug".
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\qt_test.dir\build.make:125: qt_test.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Deleting file 'qt_test.exe'
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/qt_test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/qt_test.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: qt_test] Error 2
```

I checked that the file is where it is supposed to be and I tried starting CLion as admin to give it root privileges. But that did not work. Please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: My advice is to verify that both paths are correct. Does `"C:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/lib/cmake/../../bin/Qt6Cored.dll"` exist? If it does is `"C:/Users/Moritz/CLionProjects/qt_test/cmake-build-debug"` a valid folder? If both of those are true perhaps the dll already exists in `"C:/Users/Moritz/CLionProjects/qt_test/cmake-build-debug"` and you have a program using it so you can't overwrite the existing file.

Comment: You may want to use `copy_if_different` instead of `copy`

Comment: You should not need to copy the Qt dlls - simply properly set up the Qt environment. If you want to deploy your app later on use windeployqt.

Comment: The file and folder exist. No other programm uses it. I dont use `copy`, i just click build in the IDE. And "You should not need to copy the Qt dlls"...okay why does build try to do that then? And I properly installed Qt(online installer) anything more to do?